# SQl-SERVER accidental update

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have accidently updated a row in SQL-SERVER that I should not have is there anyway to get the previous value of the row using this query:

```
UPDATE Documents
SET Name = 'Files'
WHERE Id = 950
```

Is there any way to recover the previous value?

Comment: There is; do you do backups?

Comment: yes, do not commit, do rollback

Comment: @user2310289 - do you think the OP is likely to have switched off the default autocommit behaviour of SQL Server?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  I would - see what happens when you don't

Comment: Is there only one `Document` with the `Id` 950? You just changed one `Name`, just run the same statement with the old `Name`, but if you cannot remember that and do not have a backup from before your update then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but only under certain circumstances.

If you had wrapped the `UPDATE` in a transaction, you could `ROLLBACK`. This would undo the `UPDATE`.

Assuming you didn't put it in a transaction, you need to reset the database to a previous point in time. This is only possible if you have some form of back-up on the database. How to do this is shown in [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190982.aspx)

Not that both of these options will UNDO the update, not just tell you the previous values.